# Eclipse keep file highlighted

Tags: java, eclipse

I just migrated from Eclipse 2019-06 to Eclipse 2021-03, and there's a difference that's driving me crazy, and I don't know how to have the same behavior as before.

When I lose focus in the Project Explorer view, I'm unable to view the highlighted file as before.
[image]

NOTE: What I'm looking for is not the way to show the current file (present in the editor) linked against the Project Explorer. It's just the way to keep the file that I selected in Project Explorer highlighted when it looses focus.

Answer (score 0):

The theme you are using is responsible for this behavior:

In the `Light` theme + `Default` color scheme, when the focus in on the Package Explorer:

[image: classic theme + explorer::focus]

When it is on the editor:

[image: classic theme + editor::focus]

As setting the theme to Dark litterally froze my Eclipse, I can only give you those insight on what to do:

- Check in the General > Color. You could for example change the background color to some visible one (yellow, green, ...) until you see a change in the unfocused Package Explorer. Once done, you can restore default colors and only set it on the part that needs change.
- If you use some plugin that provide more themes, check with those themes.
- Use Light theme !

Comment: What Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: The current : 2021.03

Comment: Tried changing all the colors and nothing, it's always grey